# How can I use the Google maps API in a Visual BASIC application?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, api, google-maps

I'm building a simple directions program in VB and would like to incorporate some of the features found in Google maps, but when I go to the Google maps API page (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html) it only has code for using Google maps in web sites with JavaScript, Flash etc... Nothing for desktop apps. Any way to use these APIs for my program? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what features you want, you may be able to use the Static Maps API (in a PictureBox) or the Geocoding API (using the WebClient class).

Comment: @SLaks Thanks, but sadly I need the maps to update based on the users input so the static API won't work.

Comment: @Blake: Yes they will, unless you want the users to be able to drag the map.

Comment: Oh then maybe they will work. The user doesn't have to be able to drag the map just enter an address and have the map zoom to that spot. I'll try it out.

Comment: Then the Static Maps should work fine.  Remember to escape the address in the query string.  (Call `Uri.EscapeDataString`)

Comment: OK, thanks for the tip. Just one more question, why is it necessary to escape the address? What does this accomplish?

Comment: It prevents addresses with `&` from messing up the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Since there's no VB API, you would have to embed an HTML page or Flash object in your program's GUI. Not being a VB programmer, I don't know much about how to do that.

Comment: OK. I was hoping there was another easier way but embedding an HTML page in VB isn't too hard. Thanks Matt

Comment: @Blake: just remember that your program is going to need internet access for the maps to work!

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy with fixed size maps then the Static Maps API might work for you:

> [Static Maps API V2 Developer Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)

Comment: Thanks Kev but that won't quite do what I need it to. Read comment below. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @blake - as SLaks says, you won't have the dragging feature available (unless you write your own), but you do have access to zoom and markers and a whole heap of other features you can pass parameters to in the url. Should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple download command to get this webpage https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Youraddress